# How to Extract Element Attribute Values to a List in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a complicated form with jQuery. I want to submit the values to the server in an AJAX Request.

Given this array of `<tr>` values that I've got from jQuery Datatable plugin, how can I easily extract the `data-id` values into a format suitable for submitting to the form e.g. something like:

```
{
  id: 65537, id: 32768, id: 65539
}
```

I have tried:

```
> $(table.rows().nodes())
> [<tr role=​"row" class=​"odd" data-id=​"65537">​…​</tr>​, <tr role=​"row" class=​"even" data-id=​"32768">​…​</tr>​, <tr role=​"row" class=​"odd" data-id=​"65539">​…​</tr>​]
> $(table.rows().nodes()).length
3
```

What code is needed to just get the `data-id` values?

**Updated Edit**

Actually, I've just tested the form by hardcoding the values, and I need to convert it to look like this 0 indexed array, obviously with the numbers from the id field:

```
var formData = {"products[0]": 65537,
                        "products[1]": 65540};
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want duplicate keys in an object?

Comment: I guess you want instead an array of objects or just an array because its looks like it would be enough: `$(table.rows().nodes()).map(function(){return $(this).data('id');}).get();`

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out which format I need, I'm trying to bind to a list. I think I need like products[0]: 65537, products[1]: 32768 - but I can probably make it work with the map and a counter from outside the function scope I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and the data variable will have all you want

```
$(function(){
  var data = [];
  $.each($('table.rows().nodes()'),function(k,v){
      data.push($(this).data('id'));
  });
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Thanks I used a modified version of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well just loop through each `tr` and push its `data-id` with unique `key-value` paid into an `array`.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gq06ekuc/)**

```
var rows=$(table.rows().nodes())
var values=[];
$.each($(rows),function(key,value){
    var vals ={}
    vals[key]=$(this).attr('data-id')//or values.push($(this).attr('data-id');
    values.push(vals);
});
console.log(values);
```

> Note : You cannot have duplicate keys in an object say `id` as mentioned in your question so better use some unique index which you can obtain from `key` parameter of `$.each`